# SemanticUI Dropdown hidden input value set to undefined

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, semantic-ui

I'm using SemanticUI and cell gem in a rails fullstack application.

I am rendering a table of records with a cell (`TableCell`)

Each row has a SemanticUI multiselect input and i'm using an other cell (`SelectInputCell`) to render this input.

I'm setting the default value of hidden inputs for each multi select input.

But the first hidden input value is always set to `undefined`. Everything is correct for other hidden inputs.

Here's where I set value of my `SelectInputCell`in my `TableCell.rb`

```rb
row[:active] = cell(Inputs::SelectInputCell, nil,
     choices: choices,
     multiple: true,
     value: selected_product
)
```

Where `selected_input` is a string

Here's `.html.erb` of `SelectInputCell`

```html
<input id="<%= id %>" name="<%= name %>" value="<%= value %>" type="hidden" class="<%= input_class %>">
```

Here's `.js.erb` of `SelectInputCell`

```js
$('.ui.selection.dropdown').dropdown();

$('.ui.selection.dropdown.clearable').dropdown({
  clearable: true,
})
```

I am sure that `value` variable in my `SelectInputCell` `.html.erb` is a string.

I logged values of my hidden inputs before in my `TableCell` `.js.erb` run but value of the first hidden input is already set to `undefined`.

It must be something about initialization of SemanticUI dropdown but I couldn't figure it out.

Why is this first hidden input value set to `undefined` while everything in my code and logs cry the opposite.

Thank for your help and time!